# Linq - Search table records contains any letter of search string

Tags: c#, linq

I am searching a table records which has a `FirstName = "abcxyz"` successfully with below `Linq` query.

```
db.People.Where(p => searchString.Contains(p.FirstName).ToList();
```

But I would like to search the table records which contains any of the letter in `FirstName = "abcxyz"`

Like we do in SQL -

[image]

Any suggestions would be helpful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the SQL , what you need is:

```
p.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
```

so your query would be:

```
db.People.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
```

Comment: Missing the same parenthesis that the OP is, but you got the right idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below methods in LINQ, To get data using LIKE operator in SQL

Example :

1) if you want to get data starting with some letter we are using

In SQL :-

```
select * from People where firstname LIKE '%abc';
```

In LINQ : -

```
db.People.Where(p => p.firstname.StartsWith(abc));
```

2) if you want to get data contains any letter we are using

In SQL

```
select * from people where firstname LIKE '%abc%';
```

In LINQ

```
db.people.where(p => p.Contains(abc));
```

3) if you want to get data ending with some letter we are using

In SQL

```
select * from people where firstname LIKE '%abc';
```

In LINQ

```
db.people.where(p => p.firstname.EndsWith(abc));
```